# How do I display a prop as the value of a semantic-ui-react Dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a functional React component that renders a couple of semantic-ui-react Dropdown components which are working fine, with the only exception that I can't get them to display a value other than the default value. The `options` work, the `onChange` works, but not the value. My `onChange` calls a redux action to update the state, which gets passed back to my component correctly.

**TeamSelector.js:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default props => (
  <div className="choose-team">
    <span className="team-label">Home</span>
    <Dropdown
      className="team-select-home"
      onChange={(_, data) => props.setHomeTeam(data.value)}
      options={props.availableTeams}
      placeholder={'Select Team'}
      search
      selection
      value={props.homeTeam} />
    {/* another Dropdown here */}
  </div>
)
```

If I log `props.homeTeam` I get the expected value but this isn't displayed in my Dropdown. Am I using this incorrectly? I've checked the official docs but I can't find any example of using a prop as a value, just React state.

**EDIT**
As requested the format of the `availableTeams` prop is:

```
[
  { label: 'England', value: 'England' },
  { label: 'Brazil', value: 'Brazil' },
  // more in array
]
```

My reducer takes the `value` of the team and sets it as a string on state, which gets passed down as `homeTeam` on `props`. So I know the `options` and the `onChange` are working as intended, but nothing is displayed in the Dropdown when it's changed from the default value.

**EDIT 2**

Reducer function that sets the team:

```
const setHomeTeam = (state, homeTeam) => {
  const availableTeams = allTeams
    .filter(team => team.value !== homeTeam && team.value !== state.awayTeam)
  return Object.assign(
    {},
    state,
    {homeTeam},
    {availableTeams}
  )
}
```

Comment: Does is work if you change Dropdown to a Search component?

Comment: @ToneCrate it doesn't show any options at all if I change it to a Search component (without reading the docs or changing any props!). It's more of a Dropdown I'd like anyway, the search functionality was a bonus really

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was just trying to weed out a bug I had with the Dropdown components in the past. Can you please paste the reducer where you retrieve homeTeam? You are absolutely sure it's returned as a string?

Comment: @ToneCrate no worries I appreciate the help :) I've added the function that does the actual state setting bit and I've double checked it's being returned as a string - it definitely is. In available teams both the label and the value are strings.